# How to print NsView/UiView to Bluetooth receipt printer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, printing, core-bluetooth

I have successfully print the text to the bluetooth receipt printer which as peripheral. Here are the code:

```
[self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:[@"PONG" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] forCharacteristic:ch type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithoutResponse];
```

After that, I want to print with the formatted receipt, and I think to print from the `NSView/UIView` which I have set the format. And I send it by per part, because if I send it once, it show error : "The characteristic's length is invalid". Here are the code(I have try divide it by `NSData/ Byte`):

Divide by `NSData`:

```
CGRect myRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, _myView2.frame.size.width, _myView2.frame.size.height);

NSData *printedData=[_myView2 dataWithPDFInsideRect:myRect];
NSUInteger len = [printedData length];


int slicingSize = 500;

for (int i=0; i < ceil(len/slicingSize); i++) {
        int min = i * slicingSize;
        int max = (i + 1) * slicingSize;
        if(max > len) max = len;

        NSData* tmpData = [printedData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(min, max )];

        [self.discoveredPeripheral writeValue:tmpData  forCharacteristic:characteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
 }
```

But the printed format is like the `NsView` Property like:

1. endstream
2. endobj
3. 5 0 obj
4. 119
5. endobj 
   .... etc

How could I possible to do that ? 
Thank you before..

Comment: A NSRange is with start and length, where it seems you are using start and end. So `[printedData subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(min, max-min )]`?

Comment: yeahh, my bad. it's right. But I have tried it, the printed result is still like that, not the view on UIView/NSView. It still print endstrearm endobj 5 0 obj, etc.